# Node.js - How to handle errors of TypeError: Cannot read property

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, node.js, sockets

so I have Node.js server where user logins on PHP form on index.php which has action="myweb.com:3000/" so it sends POST data.

On node.js server it retrieves POST variables and gets users username from database based on the ID from POST data.

My problem is when somebody types myweb.com:300 directly into address bar, the server crashes and I am new to Node.js so I don't understand the problem.
Server.js:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));



app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('home.jade');
});
var ip = "";
var email = "";
var username = "";
var password = "";
var user_ids = "";

//Assign POST variables;
app.post('/',function(req,res, err){
  email=req.body.email;
  password=req.body.pass;
  user_ids=req.body.userid;
  ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress;

  res.redirect("/");
});



//Client connection starts;
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket['final_user'] = "def";

    //Get users username based on his ID;
    db.query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE id='"+user_ids+"'", function(error, results, fields)
    {
    socket['final_user'] = results[0].username;
    db.query("INSERT INTO users_online (userID, username, ip) VALUES ('"+user_ids+"', '"+socket['final_user']+"', '"+ip+"')");
    });

    // Set server variables to blank since the username is already retrieved.
    ip = "";
    email = "";
    username = "";
    password = "";
    user_ids = "";



    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    db.query("DELETE FROM users_online WHERE username='"+socket['final_user']+"'");
    });


});
```

and error:

> ```
> > /var/www/myweb.com/html/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:82
> >         throw err;
> >               ^ TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined
> >     at Query._callback (/var/www/myweb.com/html/server.js:1:1456)
> >     at Query.Sequence.end (/var/www/myweb.com/html/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:96:24)
> >     at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (/var/www/myweb.com/html/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:143:8)
> >     at Query.EofPacket (/var/www/myweb.com/html/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:127:8)
> >     at Protocol._parsePacket (/var/www/myweb.com/html/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:271:23)
> >     at Parser.write (/var/www/myweb.com/html/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:77:12)
> >     at Protocol.write (/var/www/myweb.com/html/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:39:16)
> >     at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/www/myweb.com/html/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:82:28)
> >     at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
> >     at Socket.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:764:14)
> ```

Note: I have removed some bits of code which are not important (just basic functions like retrieve messages etc..)

So:

1. What does this error mean?
2. How do I handle errors like this in Node.js?

Also side problem:
If user connects and I don't reset server variables to blank, if any other user types :3000 directly in browser, the server doesnt' crash but the user that typed it gets to use the ID and username of the last joined user via PHP form.

Comment: It means `results[0]` is undefined, and you're trying to access a property `username` of an undefined variable... to handle it, check if `results` and `results[0]` exist before proceeding.

Comment: You should only run the query if you have user_ids. If user_ids isn't set it's going to be an invalid query and then your result won't have any 'username' attribute.

Comment: Okay, that worked, there is no more errors. 
Thank You, that was actually easier to fix that I expected.